# java to python converstion in processing

Tags: java, python-3.x, processing

```
walker w;

void setup(){
  size(800,600);

  w=new walker();
  background(255);
}

void draw(){
  w.step();
  w.render();
}



  class walker{
  int x,y;

  walker(){
    x=width/2;
    y=height/2;
  }

  void render(){
    stroke(0);
    point(x,y);
  }

  void step(){
    int choice = int(random(4));
    if (choice==0){
      x++;
    } else if(choice==2){
      y++;
    } else if (choice==1){
      x--;
    }else{
      y--;
    }
    x=constrain(x,0,width-1);
    y=constrain(y,0,height-1);
  }
}
```

how to convert this java code into python .
this code is random walk algorthim and how to convert this code to python.
this is done on processing editor.
can anyone please covert this code

Comment: This website is not a code writing service. You have not shown us your attempt. What part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One way to convert it is to employ someone to do the conversion work for you.

I feel employed:

```py
def setup ():
    global w
    size(800, 600)
    w = walker()
    background(255)

def draw ():
    w.step()
    w.render()

class walker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = width // 2
        self.y = height // 2 

    def render(self):
        stroke(0);
        point(self.x, self.y); 

    def step(self):
        choice = int(random(4))
        if choice == 0:
            self.x += 1
        elif choice == 2:
            self.y += 1
        elif choice == 1:
            self.x -= 1
        else:
            self.y -= 1
        self.x = constrain(self.x, 0, width-1);
        self.y = constrain(self.y, 0, height-1);
```

Comment: thanks for the code